# Catch and edit form data before form will be submitted by submit button

Tags: javascript, webforms

I need to get checkbox values data before form will be submitted using vanilla JS or jQuery, modify and continue submit.
For example:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">

  <input type="checkbox" name="cbxs" value="cb_1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cbxs" value="cb_2">

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I need to check if one single checkbox is checked to wrap it with array like `cbxs=['cb_1']`, if checked 2+ - do nothing. In this case backend is always being received array of checkboxes like `cbxs=['cb_1']` or `cbxs=['cb_1', 'cb_2']`.